# How to modify edge smoothing normals

Tags: edges, normals

I have two meshes that come together to form what will visibly look like one model. How can I make their smoothing appear as if the two objects were actually one?

A little background: I am trying to use the absolute lowest amount of verts I can because this model is for a game and there may be numerous instantiations of this model which will be rigged and animated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One thing I notice right off is the disjunction in the number of vertices in the circumference of the hand and the wrist bits of the mesh, by my count 11 in the hand and 6 in the wrist. This will cause a problem. One solution to this would be to extend the hand mesh towards the shoulder by one, and reduce the number of vertices in that mesh.

Comment: The edges line up at the seem between meshes on the wrist, so there is not a thin gap you can see through. I did this because the amount of times I loop cut the hand is more than I need for the body, and was trying to use less verts. Can you elaborate on your soulution? Is it possible to decrease the amount of loop cuts somewhere near the wrist so that no ngons are created? As I have heard, ngons are not wanted on models that will be animated. The model should be made up of quads and triangles.

Also, I do believe there are 10, not 11 verts. The hand has two more loop cuts than the arm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remodel part of the hand so that both hand and wrist meet with 6 vertices.
[image]

And or checkout how to use Blenders Data Transfer or Normal Editor Modifiers.
I rememeber trying to get those to work when they were first added a couple of years ago but failed. Way to complicated for me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the picture, that method of adding loops looks better than my method! And should work perfectly in my scenario! :D